# Powershell: Map/Unmap Network drive on a remote computer

Tags: powershell

How do I map/unmap a network share on a remote computer using powershell?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remote computer would need PSRemoting enabled (Enable-PSRemoting -Force), then you can execute the following:

Map Network Drive:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName hostname -ScriptBlock {$netobj = New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Network";$network.MapNetworkDrive("Z:","\\Server\Share")}`

Remove Network Drive:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName hostname -ScriptBlock {$netobj = New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Network";$network.RemoveNetworkDrive("Z:")}`

Answer (score 0):

What about using net.exe from powershell? Such as `net use * \\server\share /user:<domain>\<user> *`. The '*' tells net.exe to prompt for the password (you can also just pass it in the command line if you like).

Answer (score 0):

Now with PowerShell 3.0 or above use: 
    `Remove-PSDrive -Name <Drive you want Remove> -Scope Global -Force`
or 
    `Remove-SmbMapping -LocalPath (<Drive you want Remove> + ":") -UpdateProfile -Force`